# int cannot be converted to resultset

Tags: java, swing

I get when i use executeQuery() java.sql.SQLException: `Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()`

```
public boolean newStudent(String sname,String gender,
                        String level,String faculty,
                        String section,String address,
                        String contactNo,String comment)
    {
        try{
            std.setString(1,sname);
            std.setString(2,gender);
            std.setString(3,level);
            std.setString(4,faculty);
            std.setString(5,section);
            std.setString(6,address);
            std.setString(7,contactNo);
            std.setString(8,comment);
            stdRes=std.executeUpdate();
            if(res.next()){
                System.out.println("Succesfully saved!");
                return true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Data save process interrupted");
                return false;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't make your question nothing but a code dump.

Comment: What's `std`, what's `stdRes`, what's `res`?

Comment: Assuming that `std` is a `PreparedStatement` with an `INSERT` SQL statement (you should have said that too), of course you'd get that error, because `executeQuery()` is for `SELECT` statements. `executeUpdate()` returns an update count, so the following statement should be `if (stdRes != 0)`. But really: **What is your question????**

Comment: std is PreparedStatement. anyways i've solved it. thanks for your concern

Answer (score 2):

From your code, seems like the problematic line is

```
stdRes = std.executeUpdate();
```

[.executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) returns an `int`. So make sure you are assigning its result to an `int` variable:

```
int result = std.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Given the `std.setString()` statements immediately before, it can be inferred that `std` is a `PreparedStatement`, and does *not* require a `String` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! :D